# Python: Find every occurrence of specific times of day between two datetimes

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to loop through every occurrence of `00:00`, `08:00` and `16:00` between two datetimes, but `0`, `8` and `16` are dynamic, so they might be `[0,1,2,3,4..` or `[0,4,8,12...]`

---

For example if these were the two datetimes

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 6, 22, 11, 28, 793007)
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 9, 0, 11, 33, 353162)
```

and I was looking for every occurrence of midnight(00:00) and noon(12:00) I would want to receive these datetimes as a response

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 12, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 7, 12, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to loop..."*: Can you add your code and explain what the problem is you are facing? Is the output incomplete? Do you get an error? Is your loop not finishing? ...etc

Answer (score 1):

One might be able to do a little more reasoning about times and come up with a more elegant solution, but this works.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# 1 day
dt = timedelta(1)
# seconds per hour
h = 3600

#the starting and end date
start = datetime(2021, 9, 9, 12)
end = datetime(2021, 10, 9, 15)

# timeoffsets from midnight
times = [
    timedelta(0),
    timedelta(0, 9*h), 
    timedelta(0, 16*h)
]


def iter_times(start, end, times):
    
    # midnight of the starting day
    now = datetime(start.year, start.month, start.day)
    
    # iterate over days - start inclusive and end exclusive
    while now < end:
        for t in times:
            my_time = now + t
            # check that we do not exceed bounds
            if my_time < start or my_time > end:
                continue
            yield my_time
        now = now + dt
        
for t in iter_times(start, end, times):
    print(t)
```